# can't find my file after file upload in php

Tags: php, html, windows

I was using the following php script to upload a file:

```
<?php
$dest_dir="C:\Users\Maria\Documents\IT-learning";
foreach ($_FILES as $file_name => $file_array) {  
    echo "path: ".$file_array['tmp_name']."<br/>\n"; //output is "C:\Windows\Temp\phpB4C9.tmp" instead
    echo "name: ".$file_array['name']."<br/>\n";
    echo "type: ".$file_array['type']."<br/>\n";
    echo "size: ".$file_array['size']."<br/>\n";

    if (is_uploaded_file($file_array['tmp_name'])) {
        move_uploaded_file($file_array['tmp_name'], $dest_dir.$file_array['name'])
        or die ("file exists but can't be moved");
        echo "File uploaded successfully.";
    } else {
        echo "File does not exist.";
    }
} //single file is fine.  opened single file is  
?>
```

The output is like this:

```
path: C:\Windows\Temp\phpB4C9.tmp
name: test2.xml
type: text/xml
size: 4523
File uploaded successfully.
```

My problem is I don't see the `test2.xml` file on my computer except in the original directory. From my understanding, I should see it moved to `C:\Users\Maria\Documents\IT-learning`. But I don't see it either in `C:\Users\Maria\Documents\IT-learning` or in `C:\Windows\Temp\phpB4C9.tmp`.

Do I miss-understand anything?

Comment: What server package are you using for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to be careful with your backslashes in string literals:

```
$dest_dir="C:\\Users\\Maria\\Documents\\IT-learning";
```

You should double them up to prevent accidental special escape sequences.

Second, you are missing a trailing slash:

```
$dest_dir="C:\\Users\\Maria\\Documents\\IT-learning\\";
```

Since you are missing the last backslash, I believe you'll find a file named something like:

```
C:\Users\Maria\Documents\IT-learningtest2.xml
```

Also, it's not very secure to trust user input as-is (e.g., the name of a file).

Comment: Thank you so much.  Yes, it is in C:\Users\Maria\Documents\IT-learningtest2.xml.  I don't understand why I didn't find this file when I was searching for "test2".  The last backslash is absolutely necessary.  The double backslashes are not necessary in this case.

Comment: The double slash is necessary if it precedes a character like 'n', but I prefer to double all of them.